# Unsupported configuration error for creating ec2 instance with subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, subnet, terraform

I am learning terraform and try to create an EC2 instance, but run in this error:

> Error launching source instance: Unsupported: The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations.

I stripped it down to a minimal reproducible example:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-central-1"
}

resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block       = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "mySubnet" {
  vpc_id            = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"
  availability_zone = "eu-central-1a"
  cidr_block        = "${cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.main.cidr_block, 4, 1)}"
}

resource "aws_instance" "myInstance" {
  # CentOS 7 (x86_64) in Frankfurt, https://wiki.centos.org/Cloud/AWS
  ami = "ami-7cbc6e13"
  instance_type = "t2.large"
  subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.mySubnet.id}"
}
```

Using terraform version 0.9.5

Comment: Is your plan working fine??

Comment: Plan looks good, can add it as soon as I'm next to my computer again.

Comment: If plan looks good i would prefer try with t2.micro and see if it works.

Comment: Does that subnet exist? Does that AZ match the one for the subnet? The availability_zone is optional, drop it and try again.

Comment: Also this helped me understand the cidrsubnet function https://fishingcatblog.wordpress.com/2016/09/22/terraform-interpolation-cidrsubnet/